# Problems positioning text in tabs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm currently building a practice website and need some help with positioning text. The website has a system of events that creates tabs as shown in the image.There are 2 sections, highlights and events; events tabs are one smaller size and gives the error that shows the image.I am choosing tabs one by one as shown in the image to get to the tab that interests me marked with the arrow.When I put the text css style in correct position, the other styles of other tabs get all messed up. How it could not affect other tabs and simply change the position of the text in that tab?
My website is plan10.es if you want to see the error and I have not been clear enough.

Thanks a lot

http://subefotos.com/ver/?2dd8df8c55583522e391a5da7572ef1ao.jpg#codigos

The css class is as follows

```
input.paypalBuyBig {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: none;
    color: ".$textoYovipAmarillo.";
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: -217px;
    margin-top: 49px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Positioning text in tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236042/positioning-text-in-tabs)

Comment: Can you show your HTML and maybe the Javascript as well. And what do you mean by the  "the other styles of other tabs get all messed up"? - please be more specific.